# Replace NULL value in powershell output

Tags: csv, powershell

I'm really struggling with what seems to be a simple thing.  Any help is appreciated...

**tldr; i'm trying to find and replace blank or NULL values from powershell
output to "No Data"**

I am using the following powershell script to obtain installed application information

```
Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*
```

Below is sample output of the above script (filtered to my liking).  I am taking this data, exporting it to CSV, in order to import into another application for analysis at a later time.

```
Host             : Computer1
DisplayName      : AutoDWG DWG DXF Converter 2015
Version          : 
Publisher        : 
InstallDate      : 
arrival_datetime : 2015-11-03T09:42:18

Host             : Computer2
DisplayName      : Beyond Compare Version 3.1.11
Version          : 
Publisher        : Scooter Software
InstallDate      : 20150218
arrival_datetime : 2015-11-03T09:42:18
```

the CSV export puts the data in the correct format, but where items have no data for version, publisher, etc..., it represents it as ",," (see below)

```
"Computer1","AutoDWG DWG DXF Converter 2015",,,,"2015-11-03T09:54:21"
"Computer2","Beyond Compare Version 3.1.11",,"Scooter Software","20150218","2015-11-03T09:54:21"
```

When importing the CSV, the blank values are re-interpreted as NULL, which throws the program for a loop, as it is expecting a string.  I am attempting to change those to the string "No Data" but am having lots of trouble...

What would be the best way to handle this?

Comment: Are you asking for empty strings to be changed to "No Data" during export or import?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `Select-Object` would be your best bet. Just pipe the data to `Select-Object`, but customize each desired property as follows:

```
Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | 
  Select-Object Host, DisplayName, @{
    Label = "Version"
    Expression = { if ($_.Version) { $_.Version } else { "No Data" } }
  }, Other Properties
```

Comment: The custom object was there to demonstrate the creation of the object in the example, not to show it was necessary. After posting I deleted my answer because after some thought, I think there is a better way in which you don't have to make explicit the conversion for each property.

Comment: Well, i'm not importing anything... I'm using the get-itemproperty cmdlet to parse a registry key.  that data gets exported to CSV, but that's not really the point.  Looking at your select-object example, i think i can make it work.

Comment: Modified the example to reflect that.

Answer (score 4):

You could inspect the property values as they are piped from the Import-Csv cmdlet, and change them. Example:

```
Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | 
ForEach-Object { 
foreach ($p in $_.PSObject.Properties) 
{ 
 if ($p.Value -eq [string]::Empty)
 {
  $p.Value = 'No Data'
 }
} 
 Write-Output $_
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea of using $_.PSObject.Properties!  Was able to a modified version of that (since I ONLY wanted nulls, and because it doesn't handle an int that is 0 properly).  instead of the [string]::empty, used $null.  Means you don't need to write something to handle every field that comes through.  Definitely The Powershell Way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Building off of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33504435/712649), you could generate the calculated properties like this:

```
$SelectProperties = "Host","DisplayName"
$NoDataFields = "Version","Publisher","InstallDate"

$SelectProperties += $NoDataFields|ForEach-Object {
    @{
      Label = $_
      Expression = [scriptblock]::Create("if(`$_.""$_""){ `$_.""$_"" } else { ""No Data"" }")
    }
}

$Data = Import-Csv -Path "C:\SomePath.csv" | 
  Select-Object $SelectProperties
```

Answer (score 0):

Do your columns have headers?  This was how I did it, when I exported a CSV of groups and their owners.  For any group that didn't have an owner in the "ManagedBy" column, it fills the field with "No Owner" instead of a blank space:

```
$CSVData = Import-Csv $TempCSV -Header "samAccountName", "ManagedBy"  
$CSVData | %{
if($_.ManagedBy -eq "") {$_.ManagedBy="No Owner"}
} 
$CSVData | Export-Csv $Filename -NoTypeInformation
```

You could just change the "ManagedBy" to your header name and the "$_.ManagedBy" to what you need, then obviously "No Owner" would be "No Data".

Answer (score 0):

Another option that might work:

```
$TargetFile = "C:\temp\replaceNull.csv"
$File = Get-Content $TargetFile
$Output = @()
foreach ($Line in $File) {
    $Output += $Line -replace ",,",",No Data,"
}
$Output | Set-Content $TargetFile
```